# How to change differnt treeviews headers different colors

Tags: colors, pygtk, gtk2, gtktreeview

I have 3 different treeviews in 3 different windows, the last window opened by the second window, and the second window opened by the first, and what I'm trying to do is change the header row color via gtkrc file after using gtkrc_parse inside the 3rd window, and also naming all widgets with "STE" in front of them. But for all I've tried it either does not change the header color or it changes the header color, but on all windows.

In the gtkrc file I have tried widget, widget_class and class, adding *STE* here and there with no luck.

Hoping someone out there can point me in the right direction on how to make this happen.

I have managed to work out different button colors on this last window without changing other window button settings, so there is something, just stuck on the treeview ones.

This is done in gtk2 as well which could be an issue I guess.

Anyway any help or pointers would be great thanks.